# Google Analytics group user by route

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to Google analytics. I have a website with sub-applications inside it, I want to check who all the users visited a particular sub-application. How can I do this?

Comment: Need more information on the structure of your site, for example each sub-application has a dedicated folder? Are they in sub-domains? etc...

Comment: yes, different folders. I have routes like /admin, /supervisor, /superadmin, /dashboard . I want to check users visited each route.

Comment: Ok, thanks. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the Analytics code as the first item into the `<HEAD>` of every webpage you want to track (all pages of your site).

Then, if you have a structure in different folder like: /admin, /supervisor, /superadmin, /dashboard, to check users visited each route, you may to create a custom report like this:

[image]

Comment: this is only showing the no. of users visited each route. How can i get their user id's?

Comment: Need to setup User-ID https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en and track it for a User-ID view and/or in a custom dimensions, however if you are new in Google Analytics, but if you are new in Google Analytics it is difficult to explain it in this place.